# Upload File in Node.js via Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js web app. In the app I'm using Express. I need to let a user upload a picture. To do that, I've reviewed some examples online, but none seem to meet my needs. Specifically, I want to get the file that was uploaded, save it to the local disk, and do some manipulation on it. Right now, I have the following:

```
const app = this;
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/picture/upload', upload.single('myPicture'), function(req, res) {
  console.log('uploaded');
  var picture = req.file;
  console.log(picture);
  res.send({ id: 1, fileName: 'info', originalName: 'name' });
});
```

When I upload a file from my web page, I see the following in the console window:

```
uploaded
undefined
```

When I look in Fiddler, I can see that the image is being passed to the server. It's just like I'm not "accessing" it properly. How do I get an uploaded file on the server side in Node?

UPDATE:
As requested by responder:

**req.headers:**

```
{ host: 'localhost:1337',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '395665',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  origin: 'http://localhost:1337',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary[someRandomCharacters]',
  referer: 'http://localhost:1337/picture',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  cookie: '' 
}
```

**req.body:**

```
{ myPicture: 'data:image/png;base64,[LONG STRING OF ALPHANUMERIC CHARACTERS]' }
```

Thank you!

Comment: is name of the input field is `picture`?

Comment: Maybe you need to upload the file as `form-data`, with the `picture=` key

Comment: Your content type header has multipart/form-data but the data in the body is a data uri. You are uploading the file incorrectly.

Comment: @Musa, I'm uploading the picture via a `PUT` request via axios. How do I read the file on my Node server then? I can see that it's getting passed by examining Fiddler.

Comment: If you're using a PUT request shouldn't your route be `app.put`. Also currently you could just decode the base64 data form `req.body.myPicture` to get the file data.

Comment: @Musa When I decode the base64 data, I just get a file with that's black. The actual picture doesn't appear.

Comment: You did strip out the `data:image/png;base64,` before attempting to decode right?

Comment: @Musa - That was the problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the file type inputs using this `req.files`.
Try `console.log(req.files)`
`req.files` will return all uploaded files.

Comment: In my case, both `req.file` and `req.fiiles` result in undefined.